# Dynamic Enable/Disable lightning page of a lightning app

Tags: lightning-apps, navigation, lightningnavigation, lightning-page

There is a requirement, lightning app should have two lightning pages - Order and Pending Order, by default Pending Order will be disabled. And Order lightning page will be loaded. but Once user click on button on the Order page then Pending Oder link should be enabled and ID needs to be Pass/Set on click on button to Pending Order. Is it possible in lightning aura component ?

Comment: Are these pages representing the same record in different states? If so, this sounds like a fit for record types and record-type-specific layouts or pages.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to have two pages? From the way you describe the functionality it sounds that maybe it would be better to have two Lightning components which communicate with Application event in which this ID could be passed.

I do not have the whole picture so please provide more details. Are you using standard components or if they are custom, are you writing them using AURA or the new LWC?